# Mysql: Use part of returned row of data to get more data

Tags: mysql

I'm passing an id of an item to my model and I want to use this item id in a query to find it's area_id and from there return any other items that have the same area_id. I'm not sure how do that though, I looked at sub queries but it didn't seem right to me. This is my structure.

Item:

```
ID -- Title -- Area_id(FK) -- Description -- Date_added
```

Area:

```
ID -- Place -- Date_Added
```

Thanks for any help

Jonny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, select the are of you item:

```
SELECT Area_id FROM Item i WHERE ...
```

So you get an area ID

Now whe have to get all item in a given area:

```
SELECT * From Item WHERE Area_id IN (...)
```

Get the two queries together:

```
SELECT * From Item WHERE Area_id IN (SELECT Area_id FROM Item i WHERE ...)
```

That's done!

Please note that subqueries arn't good for performance, so I recommend you to benchmark and keep an eye on this query as you database grow, then optimize it as you experience performance problems.

Comment: Thanks for your time. But I want to return a series of rows and a subquery looking into it won't allow for returning more than 1 row. I get the following error: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: Edited to take care of the case where the first SELECT return one or more Area_id.
Is it what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT i2.*
FROM item i1, item i2
WHERE i1.id = :input_item_id
AND i1.area_id = i2.area_id
```

This is what's called a "self-join" and should be much more efficient than a solution using subqueries.